# Post request with jQuery and Laravel framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I need to receive data from jQuery post request, think there is some error with routs or controller, here is my post request javascript code:

```
$.post('http://localhost:8000/ajax',
                {

                    task: "comment_insert",
                    userID: _userID,
                    comment: _comment,
                    name: _name,
                    userName: _userName
                }

                ).error(
                    function(data)
                    {
                      alert("Error: "+ data); 
                    }
                 )
                .success(
                    function( data )
                    {
                        comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON( data ));
                      console.log("RESPOND TEXT:" + data);

                    }
                 );

     }
```

Also here is my routes for Laravel framework:

```
Route::post('ajax', 'AjaxController@index');
```

Controller:

```
class AjaxController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function index()
    {
             return view('ajax.ajax');

    }
}
```

my ajax.php script is into /resource/views/ajax/ajax.php
Also if I put script into /public/ajax/ajax.php all works fine....I use Laravel 5... Please help

**EDIT:**

I found what is problem but don't know how to solve.

When I disable csrf protection from: kernel.php code work anyone know how to make code work with csrf protection enabled?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The problem is that the new CSRF-protection does not work with ajax-requests. Here is what you could do:

In your master template add a new meta tag with the current token like this

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ Session::token() }}">
```

Then when sending your ajax call you add the token like this:

```
$.post('http://localhost:8000/ajax',
    {
        '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
        task: 'comment_insert',
        userID: _userID,
        comment: _comment,
        name: _name,
        userName: _userName
    })
    .error(
        ...
     )
    .success(
        ...
     );
}
```

Comment: It not soleve problem.... Here is error: POST http://localhost:8000/ajax 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Could you post the full error on pastbin and then a link to it here? You can find it in the logs (`storage/logs/laravel...`).

Answer (score 1):

Is a simple code with javascript to send methods GET,POST,PUT,DELETE

declare header:  `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ Session::token() }}">`

```
  function addCarrito(Urldir,paramt)
        {

        $(function(){
         $.post(Urldir,{ _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'), _method : 'PUT', data :  }, function(response){

               if(response != '')
                {
                 console.log('good');
                }

            });
        });
    }
```